# Who is ההוא דהוה in the Gemara?

Tags: maseches-sanhedrin

The gemara in Sanhedrin 7a brings a bunch of statements from ההוא דהוה(there was a man) who we learn many lessons from . One can learn that this is one person in all instances,or it is a different person in all cases. I suspect it's one person since its Shmuel who is always interpreting the saying of this person,it just seems like it's one person. Does anyone discuss who this person was ,or its just some random person who had some good sayings?

The reason I ask this is question is because I am aware of mefarshim who discuss who is hahu saba,and who is hahu tayah.So I figured there is a strong possibility that this random person is not so random.